# I have a dataframe with two columns .How to remove those Rows where names are Sam,Ben,Ram

Tags: python-3.x

```
Name Age
Sam.    12
Ben.     13
Rahul.   23
```

so on and so forth.
Table has around 200k columns.

Answer (score 0):

With dataframe named `df`, remove rows with conditions:

```
conditions_to_drop = (
    df[df.Name=='Sam'] | df[df.Name=='Ben'] | df[df.Name=='Ram']
)
df.drop(df[conditions_to_drop].index, inplace=True)
```